# How to setup default accounting entries in Odoo10?

Tags: odoo, open-source, odoo-10, invoice

I want to setup default account entries for creation of invoices. In that, I want to add just a customer name and the product details rest all should be there by default.
I had already given default values at so many fields but it is working only for few fields.

I want to set default values for

1. Account
2. Journal
3. Tax Account

In **Partner Form -> Accounting**

1. Account Receivable
2. Account Payable

So is there any way we can do that. For Reference check below given images

[image: Account Info]

[image: Tax Account]

[image: Accounting]

Answer (score 5):

In order to set company default *Account Receivable* and *Account Payable* properties, as administrator user go to *Settings* → *Technical* → *Company Properties*. Find a property with name *property_account_receivable_id* where the *Resource* field is not set. If such entry does not exist, create it with the following values:

- **Name** → *property_account_receivable_id*
- **Field** → *Account Receivable (res.partner)*
- **Type** → *Many2One*
- **Value** → *account.account,`<id>`*

Where `<id>` is the database ID of the account (model: `account.account`) you want to use as the default value (you can find all accounts by going to *Invoicing / Accounting* → Adviser → *Chart of Accounts*. You can find out the database ID from the URL (`id=<id>`) when you open a single record in a form view):

[image: Creating a company property for default Account Receivable]

For default *Account Payable*, analogically find or create a company property called *property_account_payable_id* with the following values:

- **Name** → *property_account_payable_id*
- **Field** → *Account Payable (res.partner)*
- **Type** → *Many2One*
- **Value** → *account.account,`<id>`*

Where `<id>` is the database ID of the account (model: `account.account`) you want to use as the default value (you can find all accounts by going to *Invoicing / Accounting* → Adviser → *Chart of Accounts*. You can find out the database ID from the URL (`id=<id>`) when you open a single record in a form view):

[image: Creating a company property for default Account Payable]

To set the default journal on invoices, as administrator user go to *Settings* → *Technical* → *User-defined Defaults* and click *Create* and fill in the following values:

- **Name** → *journal_id*
- **Model Name** → *account.invoice*
- **Default value or action reference** → `<id>`

where `<id>` is the database ID of the journal (model: `account.journal`) you want to use as the default value (you can find all journals by going to *Invoicing / Accounting* → Configuration → *Accounting* → *Journals*. You can find out the database ID from the URL (`id=<id>`) when you open a single record in a form view):

[image: Setting default journal_id on Invoice]

The value for *Account* on invoice will come from the *Customer*, once you select one, and *Tax Account* will come from taxes defined for a given product. You can configure taxes by going to *Invoicing / Accounting* → Configuration → *Accounting* → *Taxes*. Alternatively, you could set user-definde default values (like for *journal_id*) for taxes, with the following values:

- **Name** → *account_id*
- **Model Name** → *account.tax*
- **Default value or action reference** → `<id>`

where `<id>` is the database ID of the account (model: `account.account`) you want to use as the default value (you can find all accounts by going to *Invoicing / Accounting* → Adviser → *Chart of Accounts*. You can find out the database ID from the URL (`id=<id>`) when you open a single record in a form view):

[image: Setting default account_id on Account Tax]

Comment: It is set up for the single company only not for all other users. If I logged in from another user other than administrator invoice is directly getting paid and not following the workflow  Draft->Open-> Paid